# I would like to trace url redirects and echo them as links

Tags: php, redirect, echo, http-status-code-301

I would like to create a script that gets website redirects and echo the link except original link
Something like this website

https://wheregoes.com/

I tried this code but it doenst work,
some urls have multiple redirects and I want to grab them all

```
<?php 

$url="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-bOv2R-8X5JXO-14EJa-b6974c6b?tl=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL

// Uncomment to see all headers
/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);echo"<br>";
echo "</pre>";
*/

echo $url; // Voila
?>
```

Comment: Use `curl`. If you don't use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` flag, it will return the 301 code and you can get what you want from the `Location:` header.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a 301 redirect with php is by using the php's header() function. Here is an example of how to use this function:

```
// Redirect to the specified page
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com');

// Stop script execution
exit();
```

Comment: I would like to get specific website redirect like bitl.ly and print the link